# SQL SELECT without FROM clause in PHP with ODBC Firebird driver

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo, firebird

I can connect a .eft database file with Firebird driver like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Firebird/InterBase(r) driver}; dbname=$dbName;", $user, $pass);
```

When i try do a simple query

```
$stmt = pdo()->exec("select 1+1 as somma");
```

the result is that:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -104 [ODBC Firebird
>   Driver][Firebird]Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Unexpected
>   end of command - line 1, column 15 (SQLExecDirect[-104] at
>   ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_driver.c:247)' in
>   D:\PROGRAMMAZIONE\ricoplast\com\db.php:25

**Someone can help me?**

PS: When I do the same with different ODBC driver :
`$pdo = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; ...` the query works.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29 - 
"The SQL SELECT statement returns a result set of records **from one or more tables**"

Comment: https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-select.html

Comment: Both the SQL standard, and the Firebird SQL syntax require a `from` clause in a select. Some database systems don't require this, but Firebird does.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel well, at least by SQL'99 standard it should go as `select * from (values(1+1))` but I don't know many real databases that would support it. Sadly, Firebird neither (it could help creating ad-hoc pseudotables in the queries)

Comment: @Arioch'The Sure, but then you still have a `from`-clause..

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that

```
select 1+1 as somma
```

is not a valid Firebird query, you need to have a table from where to select. Try

```
select 1+1 as somma from rdb$database
```

The `rdb$database` table in Firebird is like `dual` in Oracle.